# Can Streams be closed by the method they return to?

Tags: java, stream, resources

I'm working with legacy code which opens an InputStream to a file, and I'm curious if the stream is being closed properly. What we currently have is a method which returns an InputStream invoked by a separate method which later closes it:

```
public void doThing(String path) throws Exception {

   InputStream is = getStream(path);

   try {
       ...   // Do some stuff
   } finally {
       if(is != null)
           is.close();
   }
}

public InputStream getStream(String path) throws Exception {

    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
    ...     // Do some stuff
    return is;
}
```

But I'm not certain if a call to `doThing()` properly closes all instances of the InputStream `is`. I understand that within the `doThing()` method, an instance of the InputStream is returned by `getStream()`, and is properly closed by the `finally` block. That part's clear.

What I'm not certain of is whether or not the `getStream()` method spawns a new instance of the InputStream which is not properly closed.

That is, when `getStream()` returns, is it returning a *reference* to the original object `is`, or is it returning a *new instance* of `is` with the same value?

If it's the former, then I'm confident that the `doThing()` method will have closed any and all Streams to the file. If it's the latter though, then I'm concerned I may have created another stream which is never explicitly closed. Instead, the object would just be marked for deletion by the Garbage Collector which may or may not eventually get rid of it. I'd like to avoid that.

Are all instances of `is` closed at the end of `doThing()`?

Comment: Can the `// Do some stuff` code throw an exception, so that `return is` is never reached? That is the only case I can see that could be an issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

New instances are only created by... `new` (*). If you don't see a `new` there, there isn't a new instance being created.

So, no new instance is created by the return. Provided nothing happens that throws an exception in the "do some stuff" in `getStream`, you are closing this in a likely adequate way.

A better way would use try-with-resources, which does a more thorough job of preserving exceptions.

---

(*) Ok, yes, there are some specific cases where this isn't quite true, for example string concatenation. String concatenation and autoboxing. String concatenation, autoboxing  and array declaration. I'll come in again.

But actually, the lack of `new` is syntactic sugar: somewhere, a `new` is being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Variables which have reference type hold just reference to the underlying value. You can think of it as a pointer. Passing reference between methods always passes just a refernce.

So answering your question, your stream is properly closed.